# Difference between Debug and Release in Xaml-Designer

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have some strange behavior in my project. I have my main project referencing different additional assemblies. One of them contains a little control which I want to show in the StatusBar of the main application.

Now the problem:
If I reference a debug version of this assembly dll the xaml designer shows the form and the referenced control in the statusbar. But if I reference a release version of the assembly the xaml-designer shows an error saying:

> Exception: The component 'Andy.Communication.Views.ConnectionIconView' does not have a resource identified by the URI Andy.Communication;component/views/connectioniconview.xaml'.**

But how could this be? I proofed that there is no code being executed only in debug-mode. And the resource-structure doesn't change either!

Any hint?

Edit:
Here is the structure of the solution. The dlls are in the Solution with the application, but they are referenced with nuget over our own package-server.

[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: Are you the one writing the DLL? You sure you don't have things like #IF?

Comment: Yes I'm the author of the DLL. It was also my first thought to look at something that only appears on debugging, but I found nothing.

Comment: Check that `connectioniconview.xaml` has its build action (properties) set to page. Also can you post a 'view' of your solution explorer and tell us which project references another project etc

Comment: @Athafoud - see my edit.

Comment: Check that your version of the release DLL on your nuget server is not a older version of the dll. Open the assembly up in ILSpy or similar and check it's content

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it's the other way around. The Nuget has a newer version number then the one in the project, cause the buildserver doesn't commit. But the code is the same! Also this doesn't explain why the debug version is working.